# Disallow dynamic htaccess rewritten url

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

How can i disallow in robots.txt indexing of pages

```
http://example.net/something,category1.php
http://example.net/something,category2.php
(...)
http://example.net/something,category152.php
```

I have try

```
Disallow: /something,*.php
```

But it say, i can't use wildcard (*) here.

Answer (score 0):

You can change link format and pack all `Disallow` pages into one url directory or write *program/script* to generate in `robots.txt` a `Disallow` all posible your `Disallow` link looks.

Comment: Hmm, i think i can't change it right now.

What about <a href=""  rel=nofollow>  ?

Can i use it ?

Comment: you can try but from information what i read on internet this not work propertly